# Selenium - get all children divs but not grandchildren

Tags: python, html, parsing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to parse a **html** file. There are many nested divs in this **html**. I want to get all **child** **divs**, but not **grandchildren** etc.

Here is a pattern:

```
<div class='main_div'>
    <div class='child_1'>
        <div class='grandchild_1'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='child_2'>
        ...
        ...
</div>
```

So the command I'm looking for would return  2 elements - divs which classes are 'child_1' and 'child_2'.

Is it possible?

I've tried to use `main_div.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')` but it returned all nested divs in the div.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way to find the direct `div` children of the div with class name "main_div":

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="main_div"]/div')
```

The key here is the use of a *single slash* which would make the search inside the "main_div" non-recursive finding only direct `div` children.

Or, with a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors):

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.main_div > div")
```

Comment: Yes I know that this would be the way but they aren't named 'child_n'. So I'm looking for a way how to get only the children.

Comment: Yes, this way works! Thank you very much I'm a very new in a Selenium.